# Редактирование отфильтрованных данных в Table View

Tags: swift, xcode

Изучаю ios разработку и возник следующий вопрос.
Имеется Tab Bar Controller с двумя вкладками, на каждой вкладке размещается Table View.
Имеется массив var listArr: [TaskItem] в котором размещаются задачи.

Структура TaskItem:

```
struct TaskItem {
    var title: String
    var text: String
    var completionDate: Date
    var completed: Bool
}
```

В первом Table View я вывожу задачи у которых completed = false, а во втором вывожу те, у которых completed = true. Это вкладки "Все задачи" и "Завершенные".

Фильтрую в модели так:

```
func getTasks(onlyCompleted: Bool = false) -> [TaskItem] {
        if (onlyCompleted) {
            // возвращаем завершенные задачи
            return listArr.filter { (TaskItem) -> Bool in
                TaskItem.completed
            }
        }
        
        // возвращаем все задачи кроме завершенных
        return listArr.filter { (TaskItem) -> Bool in
            !TaskItem.completed
        }
    }
```

+ имеется View Controller с формой редактирования задачи.

Проблема вот в чем. Допустим, в Table View всех задач выводятся задачи которые в массиве listArr имеют индексы 0, 1, 4, 6 так как 2, 3 и 5 - имеют флаг completed = true. Далее:

1. Щелкаю на строку номер 3
2. Открывается View Controller с формой редактирования выбранной задачи (выбирается задача корректно так как предварительно массив listArr фильтруется и уже с отфильтрованного берем по indexPath.row
3. Нажимаю кнопку "Сохранить"

И тут проблема: по нажатию на кнопку "Сохранить" редактируется не та задача, т.е. я выбрал третью строку, а под индексом 3 реально в listArr находится другой TaskItem, которая вообще уже completed = true и выводится в другом Table View.

```
func updateTask(id: Int, task: TaskItem) {
        listArr[id] = task
}
```

Вопрос: как мне отредактировать именно тот TaskItem в массиве?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен.

В структуру добавил id.

```
struct TaskItem {
    var title: String
    var text: String
    var completionDate: Date
    var completed: Bool
    var id: Int
}
```

и метод updateTask переписал так:

```
func updateTask(id: Int, task: TaskItem) {
        if let index = list.index(where: { $0.id == id }) {
            list[index] = task
        }
    }
```